# Why isn't my android reading this file in Downloads folder?

Tags: java, android

I  have a file named "mysimulation.txt" in my Downloads folder.

```
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String filename = "/mysimulation.txt";

            try {
                input = new Scanner(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + filename));
                Toast.makeText(this, "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "not found " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Why isn't my phone reading this file in the Downloads folder? 
I get a file not found Exception.

Comment: Do you have the permissions?

Comment: yeah, i do have

Comment: Use a file manager make sure the file is in the right place. And log the path in your code.Then compare them...

Comment: Can i use scanner to read files on android?

Comment: and can you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For any android greater than android 6.0 (masrshmallow). Add the following code to your java code to grant read and write permissions:

```
File file = new File(path);
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            123);
 //Check if the file is writable or readable (.canRead()) 
 Toast.makeText(this, file.canWrite() ? "y" : "no ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```